# Linux UDP max size of receive buffer

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming, udp, buffer

What's the maximum size of Linux UDP receive buffer? I thought it's limited only by available RAM, but when I set

5GB for rmem_max:

```
echo 5000000000 > /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max
```

and 4GB for the actual socket buffer (in Erlang):

```
gen_udp:listen(Port, [{recbuf, 4000000000}])
```

When I measure the buffer utilization, it shows:

```
# netstat -u6anp | grep 5050
udp6  1409995136      0 :::5050  :::*       13483/beam.smp
```

I can't exceed this 1.4GB. For smaller buffer sizes, like e.g. 500MB, actual buffer size matched the configured value. My system is Debian 6.0, the machine has 50GB RAM available.

Comment: Where does it say it's limited only by available RAM? And why do you think you need a 4GB buffer?

Comment: It doesn't. It doesn't say it's limited in any other way either. I need such a buffer to avoid data loss during longer network traffic peek.

Comment: On the contrary. It says the kernel may adjust the value you supply up or down, and advises you to call `getsockopt()` to see what value was actually allocated. I find it hard to believe you need 4GB to handle traffic peaks. Probably you should just read faster.

Comment: "It says the kernel may adjust the value you supply up or down" where did you find this information? How can you read faster than "while(true){recv(Socket)}" within one thread? I'm dropping packets after receiving them for test's sake. I'm able to read 60000 600B-sized packets per second, while it's not a problem to generate 200000/s traffic. Under these conditions the buffer fills after 16 seconds. You can't objectively say that 10s is a peek, but 20s is not. I'd rather expect, that with a better machine I'm able to survive longer peek.

Comment: I've been reading that statement in *man* pages for over 20 years. It isn't news. How do you know you're dropping the packets at the receiver?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that there is a limit in linux.
I have tried setting rmem_max to 2^32-1 with success.

```
   root@xxx:/proc/sys/net/core# echo 2147483647 > rmem_max
   root@xxx:/proc/sys/net/core# cat rmem_max
   2147483647
```

2^32 was too much:

```
   root@xxx:/proc/sys/net/core# echo 2147483648 > rmem_max
   root@xxx:/proc/sys/net/core# cat rmem_max
   -18446744071562067968
```

Setting to 5000000000 yields:

```
   root@xxx:/proc/sys/net/core# echo 5000000000 > rmem_max
   root@xxx:/proc/sys/net/core# cat rmem_max
   705032704
```

I have tested in python that setting and getting socket receive buffer with

```
   ss.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, bufferSize)
   print ss.getsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF)
```

If 'bufferSize' is less then 1024^3 program prints doubled 'bufferSize', otherwise it falls back to 256.

The value 705032704*2 = 1410065408 is close to the 1409995136 obtained by netstat.

Comment: Indeed, I haven't verify actual value being put in rmem_max. Thanks. It looks like the buffer size is limited to signed int with no explicit reason.

Comment: which kernel version? 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: @Massimo the dude hast 50 gigs of RAM, I think it's ok to assume 64bit

Comment: @lennyy it is possible for a 32bit OS to [address up to 64GB of RAM](https://serverfault.com/questions/3342/) using a CPU's [Physical Address Extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) feature. It is just that individual 32bit processes can't address more than 2-4GB max. But the OS itself can, and it can slice up that RAM amongst multiple processes however it wants by using Virtual Memory for each process' address space.

Comment: @RemyLebeau oh interesting, I didn't know that. Makes sense though. Thanks for sharing

Comment: @RemyLebeau I wonder if anyone is using that. In practice, I'm only seeing 64bit OSes in all environments I am touching for many, many years now.

Answer (score 0):

2^32-1 (2147483647, maximum 32bit signed integer)

```
root@root@localhost:~# sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=2147483647
net.core.rmem_max = 2147483647

root@localhost:~# sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=2147483648
sysctl: setting key "net.core.rmem_max": Invalid argument
net.core.rmem_max = 2147483648
```

Echoing into the `/proc` filesystem appears to overflow when attempting to set larger values.

Comment: which kernel version? 32 or 64 bit?