# How to increase UDP socket recv buffer size to its maximum for Linux program?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, networking, udp

I am trying to increase the receive buffer size for an UDP socket but the final size does not seem to be predictable :

```
    LOG_INFO("UDP echo server default receive buffer size : " << rcv_buf << " bytes");

    // increase default buffer sizes
    rcv_buf *= 3;

    LOG_INFO("trying to increase receive buffer size to : " << rcv_buf << " bytes");

    if (!SockWrap::set_recv_buf_size(m_handle, sizeof(m_sockaddr_in), rcv_buf))
        LOG_ERR("unable to set new receive buffer size");

    // checking the new size after possible modifications if any
    rcv_buf = SockWrap::recv_buf(m_handle, sizeof(m_sockaddr_in));

    if (rcv_buf == -1) {
        LOG_ERR("unable to read UDP echo server receive buffer size after modification");
    } else {
        LOG_INFO("UDP echo server new receive buffer size : " << rcv_buf << " bytes");
    }
```

Wrappers functions are :

```
bool SockWrap::set_recv_buf_size(int fd, socklen_t len, int size)
{
    // SO_RCVBUF option is an integer
    int n = setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &size, len);

    if (n == -1) {

        LOG_ERR("setsockopt : " << strerror(errno));
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and

```
int SockWrap::recv_buf(int fd, socklen_t len)
{
    // SO_RCVBUF option is an integer
    int optval;

    if (getsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &optval, &len) == -1) {

        LOG_ERR("getsockopt : " << strerror(errno));
        return -1;

    } else
        return optval;
}
```

output :

```
UDP echo server default receive buffer size : 212992 bytes
trying to increase receive buffer size to : 638976 bytes
UDP echo server new receive buffer size : 425984 bytes
```

I have check the limits of my system in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4`:

```
cat udp_rmem_min
4096
cat udp_mem
186162  248216  372324
```

and in `/proc/sys/net/core`

```
cat rmem_max
212992
cat rmem_default
212992
```

So the first output seems pretty clear, the default recv buffer value is 212992 bytes which is defined by `rmem_default`.

But then size is increased and suprisingly greater than `rmem_max` but still not what i wanted.

Where this final value (425984 bytes) comes from ?

Is this value a maximum and does it depends on how much memory is currently used by the kernel ?

**EDIT :**

Following the answer, i have tested other values and it's seems even possible to set `rmem_default` to be greater than `rmem_max` :

```
echo 500000 > /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default
cat /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default
500000
```

Now before `setsockopt` is called, `getsockopt` returns (as always) `rmem_default`, not `rmem_default * 2` which is 500000.

But if i use `setsockopt` to set the value to 500000 then `getsocktop` returns `rmem_max * 2` which is 425984.

So it's seems that using `/proc` interface allows more control on the buffer size than `setsockopt`.

What is the purpose of `rmem_max` if `rmem_default` can be greater ?

```
/* from kernel 5.10.63 net/core/sock.c */
case SO_RCVBUF:
    /* Don't error on this BSD doesn't and if you think
     * about it this is right. Otherwise apps have to
     * play 'guess the biggest size' games. RCVBUF/SNDBUF
     * are treated in BSD as hints
     */
    __sock_set_rcvbuf(sk, min_t(u32, val, sysctl_rmem_max));
    break;
```

and

```
static void __sock_set_rcvbuf(struct sock *sk, int val)
{
       /* Ensure val * 2 fits into an int, to prevent max_t() from treating it
        * as a negative value.
        */
        val = min_t(int, val, INT_MAX / 2);
        sk->sk_userlocks |= SOCK_RCVBUF_LOCK;
        /* We double it on the way in to account for "struct sk_buff" etc.
         * overhead.   Applications assume that the SO_RCVBUF setting they make
         * will allow that much actual data to be received on that socket.
         *
         * Applications are unaware that "struct sk_buff" and other overheads
         * allocate from the receive buffer during socket buffer allocation.
         *
         * And after considering the possible alternatives, returning the value
         * we actually used in getsockopt is the most desirable behavior.
         */
        WRITE_ONCE(sk->sk_rcvbuf, max_t(int, val * 2, SOCK_MIN_RCVBUF));
}
```

But maybe this edit should be another (related) question.

Thank you.

Comment: This can't be a coincidence: `425984 = 212992 * 2`

Answer (score 5):

Per the [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html):

> `SO_RCVBUF`
> Sets or gets the maximum socket receive buffer in bytes. The kernel doubles this value (to allow space for bookkeeping overhead) when it is set using [setsockopt(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsockopt.2.html), and this doubled value is returned by [getsockopt(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getsockopt.2.html).  The default value is set by the `/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default` file, and the maximum allowed value is set by the `/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max` file.  The minimum (doubled) value for this option is 256.

So, in your case, `rmem_max` is `212992`, so your input is being reduced from `638976` to `212992`, and then `setsockopt()` is doubling it, hence `425984`.

Comment: Unrelated but max for UDP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460261/linux-udp-max-size-of-receive-buffer

Comment: Ok but then the _bookkeeping overhead_ bytes cannot be used to store UDP datagrams ? So the effective size of the buffer is still half of what getsockopt returns ?

Comment: `rmem_max` is 212992 but if using `setsockopt` doubles this value which become larger than `rmem_max` then what is the limit 212992 or 425984 ?